# Decrypting PyNaCL encrypted file with js-NaCl

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, libsodium

I have a file that has been encrypted with a PyNaCl Box() as well as the resulting key. I am having issues with decrypting it with Node.js and js-NaCl. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `js-NaCl` properly so it could decrypt data without issues.

Comment: @Olvin
I have both a public and private key generated inside of PyNaCL.
What would be the method I should use inside js-NaCL?